# Store session from initial login via POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authorization, fetch

I am running nodeJS and have the following function:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function createCustomer() {
  let response = await fetch('https://sampleurl.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: 'username=usernameHere&password=passwordHere',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
      }
  });

  tempVar = await response.json();
  console.log(tempVar);
```

This logs in and authenticates, providing me a successful response.

However if I then try and do the next step, it fails with an unauthorized error.

```
let response2 = await fetch('https://sampleurl.com/list', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    }
  });

  tempVar2 = await response2.json();
  console.log(tempVar2);
```

In python I use requests.Session() and do the initial authorization and then any API call after that just begins with 'session' and it works. For example::

```
session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://sampleurl.com/login',data={'username':'usernameHere','password':'passwordHere'})

response = session.get('https://sampleurl.com/list').json()
print(response)
```

This is the functionality I am trying to replicate, but I can't figure out how to store the session.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Using Express.
**Edit2:** This is not hitting an API I am running the server for, I am not looking for how to build this feature as the API server, rather just connect to an external API.

Comment: Which web application server you are using in nodejs ? if express then search for express-session...otherwise you can search accordingly

Comment: How do you atuhtenticate against this API? Using an [auth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header?